# Access Instance-property in Coffeescript within nested

Tags: express, coffeescript

so I am using express within a node-app. As my app is getting bigger I want to put my routes into extra files. I seem to be able to get hold of the bugDB if I just get rid of the intermediate get object. But I can't access the bugDB in the inner object. Any suggestions? Maybe there is even a more nice code pattern for how to accomplish this more elegantly.

I would appreachate your help. Thanks in advance. (As I am not a native speaker I couldn't find others with a similar problem, if you know how to phrase the question better, please show me the way :) )

```
BUGROUTER.COFFEE
class BugsRouter
    constructor: (@bugDB)->   // instance-variable with databaselink
        return

    get:{
        allBugs: (req, res)=>
            console.log "db", @bugDB // this gives me undefined
                                     // is "this" in the get context? 
            @bugDB.allDocs {include_docs: true}, (err, response)->
                res.json 200, response
        }
module.exports = BugsRouter

SERVER.COFFEE
BugsRouter = require "./routes/BUGROUTER"
bugsRouter = new BugsRouter(bugDB)
console.log bugsRouter.bugDB # this is working
app.get    "/bugs/all", bugsRouter.get.allBugs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, seems like I found a better solution after all:

```
class Test
    constructor: ->
        @testVariable = "Have a nice"
        return

    Object.defineProperties @prototype,
        get:
            enumerable :true
            get:->
                {
                    day: => @testVariable + " day"
                    week: => @testVariable + " day"
                }

console.log (new Test()).get.day()
```

This allows me to call `(new Test()).get.day()` the way I wanted.
Live version at: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmo24068/)

Answer (score 2):

Sub-objects don't work like that. When you say this:

```
class C
    p:
        f: ->
```

Then `p` is just a plain object that happens to be a property on `C`'s prototype, it will have no special idea of what `@` should be inside `f`. And if you try to use a fat-arrow instead:

```
class C
    p:
        f: =>
```

then you're accidentally creating a namespaced class function called `f` so `@` will be `C` when `f` is called. In either case, saying:

```
c = new C
c.p.f()
```

is the same as:

```
c = new C
p = c.p
p.f()
```

so `f` will be called in the context of `p` rather than `c`.

You can get around this if you don't mind manually binding the functions inside `get` when your `constructor` is called:

```
constructor: (@bugDB) ->
    @get = { }
    for name, func of @constructor::get
        @get[name] = func.bind(@)
```

This assumes that you have [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) available. If you don't then you can use any of the other binding techniques (`_.bind`, `$.proxy`, ...). The `@get = { }` trick is needed to ensure that you don't accidentally modify the prototype's version of `@get`; if you're certain that you'll only be creating one instance of your `BugsRouter` then you could use this instead:

```
constructor: (@bugDB) ->
    for name, func of @get
        @get[name] = func.bind(@)
```

to bind the functions inside the prototype's version of `get` rather than the instance's local copy.

You can watch this simplified demo to see what's going on with `@` in various cases, keep an eye on the `@flag` values to see the accidental prototype modification caused by not using `@get = { }` and `@constructor::get`:

```
class C1
    get:
        f: -> console.log('C1', @)

class C2
    get:
        f: => console.log('C2', @)

class C3
    constructor: ->
        @flag = Math.random()
        for name, func of @get
            @get[name] = func.bind(@)
    get:
        f: -> console.log('C3', @)

class C4
    constructor: ->
        @flag = Math.random()
        @get  = { }
        for name, func of @constructor::get
            @get[name] = func.bind(@)
    get:
        f: -> console.log('C4', @)

for klass in [C1, C2, C3, C3, C4, C4]
    o = new klass
    o.get.f()
```

Live version of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8XR7Z/

Comment: As I cannot upvote yet(Will do as soon as I can): *thumbsup* thank you kindly for this thorough explanation! This helps me a lot.

Comment: So would you suggest to avoid subobjects as much as possible? I liked them for modularity

Comment: @Gundon You can use them if you want but you have to manually bind them somewhere and you need to keep in mind that binding them isn't free. Just the usual question of tradeoffs really.